401 Unauthorized on Wazuh Dashboard via SAML SSO (Onelogin)
I have configured Wazuh (version 4.8.1, installed using Docker) for SSO via SAML 2.0 following the official Wazuh documentation :enter link description here
Additionally, I referred to a related GitHub issue for guidance. However, when attempting to log into the Wazuh Dashboard, I encounter a 401 Unauthorized error after being redirected back from the OneLogin IdP.

Here’s the relevant configuration section from my /usr/share/wazuh-indexer/opensearch-security/config.yml file:

basic_internal_auth_domain:
        description: "Authenticate via HTTP Basic against internal users database"
        http_enabled: true
        transport_enabled: true
        order: 0
        http_authenticator:
          type: "basic"
          challenge: false
        authentication_backend:
          type: "intern"
      saml_auth_domain2:
        http_enabled: true
        transport_enabled: true
        order: 1
        http_authenticator:
          type: "saml"
          challenge: true
          config:
            idp:
              metadata_file: '/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/opensearch-security/metadata_onelogin.xml'
              entity_id: 'https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/be43xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
            sp:
              entity_id: wazuh-saml
            kibana_url: https://x.x.x.x 
            roles_key: Roles
            exchange_key: 'x509 Certificate for signing the request'
        authentication_backend:
          type: noop


Also /usr/share/wazuh-indexer/opensearch-security/roles_mapping.yml file :

## Default roles mapping

all_access:
  reserved: true
  hidden: false
  backend_roles:
  - "admin"
  - "wazuh-admin"
  hosts: []
  users: []
  and_backend_roles: []
  description: "Maps admin to all_access"


On Wazuh dashboard configuration side, here's opensearch_dashboards.yml file configurations :

server.host: x.x.x.x
server.port: 5601
opensearch.hosts: https://wazuh.indexer:9200
opensearch.ssl.verificationMode: certificate
opensearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: ["securitytenant","Authorization"]
opensearch_security.multitenancy.enabled: false
opensearch_security.readonly_mode.roles: ["kibana_read_only"]
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.key: "/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/wazuh-dashboard-key.pem"
server.ssl.certificate: "/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/wazuh-dashboard.pem"
opensearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: ["/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/root-ca.pem"]
uiSettings.overrides.defaultRoute: /app/wz-home
opensearch_security.auth.type: ["basicauth","saml"]
server.xsrf.allowlist: ["/_opendistro/_security/saml/acs", "/_opendistro/_security/saml/logout", "/_opendistro/_security/saml/acs/idpinitiated"]
opensearch_security.session.keepalive: false
opensearch_security.auth.multiple_auth_enabled: true

I've added a role mapping on the Wazuh dashboard:
enter image description here
Here is the configuration on the OneLogin side :
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
When I tried to access the Wazuh Dashboard, I encountered the following errors in the wazuh.indexer logs :
[wazuh.indexer] No 'Authorization' header, send 401 and 'WWW-Authenticate Basic


Here are the Wazuh.dashboard logs :
wazuh.dashboard-1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2024-11-15T15:59:21Z","tags":[],"pid":54,"method":"get","statusCode":302,"req":{"url":"/auth/saml/login?nextUrl=%2F&redirectHash=false","method":"get","headers":{"host":"<wazuh_dashboard_url>","x-real-ip":"x.x.x","x-forwarded-for":"x.x.x.x","x-forwarded-proto":"https","connection":"close","sec-ch-ua":"\"Brave\";v=\"131\", \"Chromium\";v=\"131\", \"Not_A Brand\";v=\"24\"","sec-ch-ua-mobile":"?0","sec-ch-ua-platform":"\"Windows\"","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","sec-gpc":"1","accept-language":"fr-FR,fr","sec-fetch-site":"same-origin","sec-fetch-mode":"navigate","sec-fetch-dest":"document","referer":"https://<wazuh_dashboard_url>/auth/saml/captureUrlFragment?nextUrl=%2F","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br, zstd"},"remoteAddress":"x.x.x.x","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","referer":"https://<wazuh_dashboard_url>/auth/saml/captureUrlFragment?nextUrl=%2F"},"res":{"statusCode":302,"responseTime":37,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /auth/saml/login?nextUrl=%2F&redirectHash=false 302 37ms - 9.0B"}
wazuh.dashboard-1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-11-15T16:00:03Z","tags":
["error","opensearch","data"],"pid":54,"message":"[ResponseError]: Response Error"}


As soon as I enter the credentials of the user with the appropriate rights to access the wazuh dashboard via SSO, I encounter this error message
enter image description here
Thank you in advance, and if you need any additional information, please let me know. I've been struggling with this issue for three months now
